# how to set a property globally in wso2 ESB

Tags: properties, wso2, session-management, wso2-esb

I am trying to figure out how to implement session management in wso2 esb.So i have written a class mediator which generates session_ID that i want to store.For storing the session id I am using following code as:

```
org.apache.axis2.context.ServiceContext serviceContext = org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext
            .getCurrentMessageContext().getServiceContext();
serviceContext.setProperty("SessionIDGlobal", uuid);
```

But while running it in my esb's proxy it throws null pointer exception at getCurrentMessageContext part.I have followed another approach where-in i am storing the sessionID in property mediator and tried to get its value but when i click postRequest operation after generateSessionID operation from try-it. all the property gets reset and my sessionID property gives me null value. What should i do to rectify this problem? Is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create servicecontext like this;

```
ConfigurationContext cfgCtx =(((Axis2MessageContext) synCtx).getAxis2MessageContext(). getConfigurationContext();

cfgCtx.getOperationContext().getServiceContext();
```

Comment: uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
ConfigurationContext cfgCtx = (((Axis2MessageContext)messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext().getConfigurationContext());
//cfgCtx.setProperty("SessionUUID", uuid);
ServiceContext serviceContext = cfgCtx.getOperationContext(messageContext.getMessageID()).getServiceContext();serviceContext.setProperty("SessionUUID", uuid);

Comment: this is the code that i have written to set the uuid but again it is giving me nullpointer exception  null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openoandm.www.xml.isbmOpenPub.OpenPublicationSkel.mediate(OpenPublicationSkel.java:50)

Comment: Thanks ratha for helping me. It did work for me after making some changes.Thanks a lotttt

Answer (score 0):

You should store in the Message context but you have stored in the service Context. please refer this to understand how you can set the properties at different scopes. Synapase (default), Axis2, Transport etc.

Please refer this blog post for complete details.
http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/02/wso2-esb-property-mediator-different.html