# how to add sessionID or user ID to request header using wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 ESB to secure my service. service is available through wsdl, and this service is insecured. My scenario is as follows: A system expose some apis or services, and they are insecured. I want to create proxy services to these services. If client invokes the proxy service, ESB should first check if the request contains the session ID, if yes, client can invoke the backend service. if no, client is redirect to a log in page. I think ESB can do this by adding a session ID or user ID header to the request, but I am lack of docs. can someone help?
and I have read [1], and conclude ESB will meet my demand.

[1] http://www.ws02.net/library/knowledge-base/convert-http-basic-authentication-ws-security-username-token/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting a custom header field from user request. Since you are creating proxies with the associated WSDL, you can add [SOAP Header requirement in your wsdl](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap%3aheader) and associate that WSDL to the proxy (using publishWSDL option). So, when user send request to your proxy he might need to add that particular header.

Other routing logic you can handle within proxy configuration

Comment: thanks, Ratha. I think I had read the artical and sample about sending  a soap request by adding a header. is there any sample you can show me on line, so that I can better understand the process of this user case.

Comment: I think I am quite a green hand about session management and don't know how to test if the sample works well with the new header. so it would be very nice if you can provide some sample codes and tools and help to demo the process. :)

Comment: @wiwengweng how your proxy looks like? how did you configure your service..You can check following guides to demonstrate your session management technique. http://wso2.com/library/3264/   http://wso2.com/library/articles/axis2-session-management-part-2/   http://wso2.com/library/334/

Comment: And here is another reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031278/how-to-set-a-property-globally-in-wso2-esb